# Let $LOOP_{TM}$ be descriptor language of all touring machines that won't halt for any input. Show reduction of $HALT_{TM}$ to $LOOP_{TM}$

Tags: automata, turing-machines

Question from Homework that I'm having difficult to answer on:

> Let $LOOP_{TM} = \{\langle M\rangle \mid \text{M is a TM that does not halt on any input w}\}$
>
> Let $LOOP_{TM}$ be descriptor language of all Turing machines that won't
> halt for any input. Show reduction of $HALT_{TM}$ to $LOOP_{TM}$
>
> Note: $HALT_{TM} = \{ (M, w) \mid M \text{ is a TM that halts on $w$}\}$.

Can you give me some hints and guidelines to solve it?

Thanks in advance.